# Why does my state persist on screen change?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, use-state

I am developing a React Native app and I am currently using a component in 2 different places of my app. I navigate from one place to another using a Drawer Navigator (React Navigation v6). This component updates a state when receiving a response from an API. However, if I switch to the other place where this component gets rendered, the state remains (therefore the visual message from the API appears inside it).

Why does this happen? Shouldn't all states reset on unmount and get the initial value (the one passed to `useState()`) when the component gets mounted again? This not the behavior I want and from what I know, this was not supposed to happen.

What can I do to make my state not persist on screen change? I have implemented the code below to be executed when a menu screen is selected, but has no effect on this issue:

```
navigation.dispatch(
        CommonActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            key: null,
            routes: [{ name: targetScreen }]
        })
```

Comment: If you are navigating in nested stack screen then your initial screen doesn't unmount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior in react-native differs from react. This is documented [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle/).

> If you are coming to react-navigation from a web background, you may assume that when user navigates from route A to route B, A will unmount (its componentWillUnmount is called) and A will mount again when user comes back to it. While these React lifecycle methods are still valid and are used in react-navigation, their usage differs from the web.

Consider a screen `A` and a screen `B`. Suppose we navigate from `A to B`.

> When going back from B to A, componentWillUnmount of B is called, but componentDidMount of A is not because A remained mounted the whole time.

This is valid for all navigators in react-native-navigation. Thus, if we have a tab bar navigation with 5 tabs, and each tab nests a `Stack`, then we could navigate on one stack to a certain depth, then switch the tab, and then switch the tab back again, and all screens visited will remain mounted.

**Edit:** In response to the comments. The recommended standard pattern to resolve your issue is as follows.

```js
// some state in my component
const [state, setState] = useState()

useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      // set state to initial value
      setState()
    }, [])
);
```

This is described [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/).

Comment: Okay, so if I want my state to reset to its initial value, what should I do?

Comment: Consider my update please.

Comment: This breaks my flow, because now the state resets to empty string every time its value changes, therefore the containing message is no longer displayed before resetting. It just resets instantly. The desired behavior is to only reset the state whenever the screen is changed.

Comment: remove `state` from the dependency array.

Comment: with an empty dependency array it has no effect

Comment: I have just tested it. Screen A contains the useFocusEffect as provided in my answer. Navigating to Screen B and navigating back to A triggers the useCallback.

Comment: [Here is a working snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/usefocuseffect).

Comment: The component that is re-rendered, which has the persisting state, is a child component in Screen A, and wrapped in a modal (from `react-native-modal`) that pops up when I press a button in Screen B. I have added your code inside the component and it does nothing in my case.

Comment: Could you make a minimal example in a snack? Otherwise it is hard to tell what is going wrong.

Comment: It was apparently from somewhere else :( I noticed this when creating the snack. The state was being updated on component mount based on a redux state that was holding the message, which was the one that persisted. I'm sorry for this, and thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your component does not unmount when you navigate out of component. Consider manually reseting your state inside this hook [useFocusEffect](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Hook called [Use Focus Effect](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/)

You can view the sample code below

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';
// some state in my component
const [state, setState] = useState()

useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      // set state to initial value
      setState()
    }, [])
);
```